# Designing a Stock App would like some advice

Tags: java, android

I want to develop an android app that provides market data. I've been reading different tutorials and I have an idea on how I could go about making one but there are so many approaches I wanted to make sure I'm taking the right approach and doing all the right practices.

Basically I wanted to make an app where I can make a list of stocks with up to date market data. I will be getting the market data from a web server. If I click on one of the items I can see another screen with more information regarding the stock. There are a lot more things I want to do but I figured I'll start with that.

So I was thinking I'd have to make a database to store the list of stocks as well as the market data. The list and the details page will draw the data from the database, while I would have to have a service to poll the data from the server and save it on the database.

Will I need to make a content provider if I don't plan to share the data or should I just make a local database? Is there an advantage if I use a content provider?

Is a service the best approach to keep my data fresh? Is there a way for my service to keep getting data from my web server at regular intervals? Not yet sure to do this but based on what I read services seem like the best approach.

I'd like to hear from the community how they would design this, at least it will help me identify what I have to learn and what to search for in the net hehe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not wish to share your data among other applications there is no need to use a content provider.  There is no advantage to using one other than providing a common interface to sharing the data.

Yes a service is the best way.  However you will more than likely need to get the service to start a thread to do the data retrieval.  To get your service started at regular intervals, use a `BroadcastReceiver` and an `AlarmManager`.  Register the `BroadcastReceiver` and an `intent-filter` in your manifest.xml.  Use the `AlarmManager` to fire a `PendingIntent` which will be picked up by your`BroadcastReceiver` which will then start your `Service` which would in turn start your `Thread` or `AsyncTask` to retreive the data and write it to your database.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start reading on those different classes. Now I have an idea on how to keep my database up to date, but what would be best to update my UI? I plan to have 2 screens, one for the list and one for a detailed view of any of the list items. Is there something I can use to notify the current activity to retrieve data from the db? Would that be the best way to keep my views with the latest data?

Comment: When your activities become visible, get them to query the database.  If you extend `CursorAdapter` or use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and pass in your `Cursor` when instantiating the adapter, you can use this as you `ListView` adapter.  You can specify in the instantion of your custom `CursorAdapter` to reQuery and update the view.  Hope that helps more.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply was away without access to a computer. Thanks that really helped I'm starting to read up on those classes you listed. My question is if a user stays on an activity and I want that activity to refresh the data should I use some sort of timer that will just regularly call my service?

Comment: I'd probably still use the AlarmManager to kick off autoupdates whether the activity is running or not.

Comment: Thanks Sugarynugs! This is my first time developing an android app but you've really helped in a big way! I'll be spending the next few days studying then try building it. Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi thanks again for all the help everything you said was what I needed. I just have a few questions: On another scenario let's say I don't have to save to a database, because the screens have to show fresh data always; stale data is useless. I have activities with different representations of data which has to be regularly updated from my web server. Making a service for each activity/screen doesn't seem like the right thing to do. Would having each activity have their own AsyncTask be better? I don't know yet how to keep it regularly updating with AsyncTasks. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Hi Grish.  What you would do in that instance is use an `ArrayAdapter` with your `ListView`.  Yes having each Activity with its own AsyncTask would be best and have the service execute the relevant one.  Another solution would be to have a single AsyncTask and use a custom class to give a mechanism of being able to pass a payload.  Have a look here http://jyro.blogspot.com/2009/11/android-asynctask-template.html for example code demonstrating the principle.

Comment: I was looking in detail at AsyncTask and you can only have 5 running concurrently and it is basically just a managed thread pool.  You may want to look at doing your own with `Thread` or `Runnable`.  Also have a look at `Looper` (a thread which never ends and has a message queue).  Updating the UI from your own implementation is easy using `Activity.runOnUiThread`.

Comment: Thanks so much! Ok based on what I read I think this is how I would implement my app. I have 4 activities that will show data that needs to be fresh. I refresh the data by getting a JSON string from a webserver. Each activity will have its own AsyncTask which does the retrieval of data and publishing the results to the screen. On start of an activity I will call a non sticky service, which will run the current activity's AsyncTask. I plan to resolve which AsyncTask to call based on the parameters in my intent. OnClose(Or should it be OnPause?) of an Activity I will cancel any pending alarms.